# how to find convolution between two functions?

Tags: convolution

I have some problems with the convolution between two functions.  i want to find the convolution of two models.  The two models are given by `gd` and `gl`. The parameters are :

```
ws = 4.3266;
wd = 4.7556; 
wss = 0.205; 
wdd = 0.038; 
q1 = 0.15177;

eps1 = 2*(t - ws)/(2*wss);
eps2 = 2*(t - wd)/(wdd);
```

I want to get a Voigt function by using the convolution of the above two functions,

```
 gd[t_] = 1/(1 + eps1^2);
 gl[t_] = 1 - ((eps2 + q1)^2)/(1 + eps2^2);

Voi[t_] := NIntegrate[gd[ts]*gl[t - ts], {ts, -Infinity, Infinity}]

fitplot = Plot[{gd[t], gl[t], Voi[t_]}, {t, 4, 5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Green, Blue, Red}]
```

My data is

```
{{4.2056}, {4.2066}, {4.2076}, {4.2086}, {4.2096}, {4.2106}, {4.2116}, 
{4.2126}, {4.2136}, {4.2146}, {4.2156}, {4.2166}, {4.2176}, {4.2186}, 
{4.2196}, {4.2206}, {4.2216}, {4.2226}, {4.2236}, {4.2246}, {4.2256}, 
{4.2266}, {4.2276}, {4.2286}, {4.2296}, {4.2306}, {4.2316}, {4.2326}, 
{4.2336}, {4.2346}, {4.2356}, {4.2366}, {4.2376}, {4.2386}, {4.2396}, 
{4.2406}, {4.2416}, {4.2426}, {4.2436}, {4.2446}, {4.2456}, {4.2466}, 
{4.2476}, {4.2486}, {4.2496}, {4.2506}, {4.2516}, {4.2526}, {4.2536}, 
{4.2546}, {4.2556}, {4.2566}, {4.2576}, {4.2586}, {4.2596}, {4.2606}, 
{4.2616}, {4.2626}, {4.2636}, {4.2646}, {4.2656}, {4.2666}, {4.2676}, 
{4.2686}, {4.2696}, {4.2706}, {4.2716}, {4.2726}, {4.2736}, {4.2746}, 
{4.2756}, {4.2766}, {4.2776}, {4.2786}, {4.2796}, {4.2806}, {4.2816}, 
{4.2826}, {4.2836}, {4.2846}, {4.2856}, {4.2866}, {4.2876}, {4.2886}, 
{4.2896}, {4.2906}, {4.2916}, {4.2926}, {4.2936}, {4.2946}, {4.2956}, 
{4.2966}, {4.2976}, {4.2986}, {4.2996}, {4.3006}, {4.3016}, {4.3026}, 
{4.3036}, {4.3046}, {4.3056}, {4.3066}, {4.3076}, {4.3086}, {4.3096}, 
{4.3106}, {4.3116}, {4.3126}, {4.3136}, {4.3146}, {4.3156}, {4.3166}, 
{4.3176}, {4.3186}, {4.3196}, {4.3206}, {4.3216}, {4.3226}, {4.3236}, 
{4.3246}, {4.3256}, {4.3266}, {4.3276}, {4.3286}, {4.3296}, {4.3306}, 
{4.3316}, {4.3326}, {4.3336}, {4.3346}, {4.3356}, {4.3366}, {4.3376}, 
{4.3386}, {4.3396}, {4.3406}, {4.3416}, {4.3426}, {4.3436}, {4.3446}, 
{4.3456}, {4.3466}, {4.3476}, {4.3486}, {4.3496}, {4.3506}, {4.3516}, 
{4.3526}, {4.3536}, {4.3546}, {4.3556}, {4.3566}, {4.3576}, {4.3586}, 
{4.3596}, {4.3606}, {4.3616}, {4.3626}, {4.3636}, {4.3646}, {4.3656}, 
{4.3666}, {4.3676}, {4.3686}, {4.3696}, {4.3706}, {4.3716}, {4.3726}, 
{4.3736}, {4.3746}, {4.3756}, {4.3766}, {4.3776}, {4.3786}, {4.3796}, 
{4.3806}, {4.3816}, {4.3826}, {4.3836}, {4.3846}, {4.3856}, {4.3866}, 
{4.3876}, {4.3886}, {4.3896}, {4.3906}, {4.3916}, {4.3926}, {4.3936}, 
{4.3946}, {4.3956}, {4.3966}, {4.3976}, {4.3986}, {4.3996}, {4.4006}, 
{4.4016}, {4.4026}, {4.4036}, {4.4046}, {4.4056}, {4.4066}, {4.4076}, 
{4.4086}, {4.4096}, {4.4106}, {4.4116}, {4.4126}, {4.4136}, {4.4146}, 
{4.4156}, {4.4166}, {4.4176}, {4.4186}, {4.4196}, {4.4206}, {4.4216}, 
{4.4226}, {4.4236}, {4.4246}, {4.4256}, {4.4266}, {4.4276}, {4.4286}, 
{4.4296}, {4.4306}, {4.4316}, {4.4326}, {4.4336}, {4.4346}, {4.4356}, 
{4.4366}, {4.4376}, {4.4386}, {4.4396}, {4.4406}, {4.4416}, {4.4426}, 
{4.4436}, {4.4446}, {4.4456}, {4.4466}, {4.4476}, {4.4486}, {4.4496}, 
{4.4506}, {4.4516}, {4.4526}, {4.4536}, {4.4546}, {4.4556}, {4.4566}, 
{4.4576}, {4.4586}, {4.4596}, {4.4606}, {4.4616}, {4.4626}, {4.4636}, 
{4.4646}, {4.4656}, {4.4666}, {4.4676}, {4.4686}, {4.4696}, {4.4706}, 
{4.4716}, {4.4726}, {4.4736}, {4.4746}, {4.4756}, {4.4766}, {4.4776}, 
{4.4786}, {4.4796}, {4.4806}, {4.4816}, {4.4826}, {4.4836}, {4.4846}, 
{4.4856}, {4.4866}, {4.4876}, {4.4886}, {4.4896}, {4.4906}, {4.4916}, 
{4.4926}, {4.4936}, {4.4946}, {4.4956}, {4.4966}, {4.4976}, {4.4986}, 
{4.4996}, {4.5006}, {4.5016}, {4.5026}, {4.5036}, {4.5046}, {4.5056}, 
{4.5066}, {4.5076}, {4.5086}, {4.5096}, {4.5106}, {4.5116}, {4.5126}, 
{4.5136}, {4.5146}, {4.5156}, {4.5166}, {4.5176}, {4.5186}, {4.5196}, 
{4.5206}, {4.5216}, {4.5226}, {4.5236}, {4.5246}, {4.5256}, {4.5266}, 
{4.5276}, {4.5286}, {4.5296}, {4.5306}, {4.5316}, {4.5326}, {4.5336}, 
{4.5346}, {4.5356}, {4.5366}, {4.5376}, {4.5386}, {4.5396}, {4.5406}, 
{4.5416}, {4.5426}, {4.5436}, {4.5446}, {4.5456}, {4.5466}, {4.5476}, 
{4.5486}, {4.5496}, {4.5506}, {4.5516}, {4.5526}, {4.5536}, {4.5546}, 
{4.5556}, {4.5566}, {4.5576}, {4.5586}, {4.5596}, {4.5606}, {4.5616}, 
{4.5626}, {4.5636}, {4.5646}, {4.5656}, {4.5666}, {4.5676}, {4.5686}, 
{4.5696}, {4.5706}, {4.5716}, {4.5726}, {4.5736}, {4.5746}, {4.5756}, 
{4.5766}, {4.5776}, {4.5786}, {4.5796}, {4.5806}, {4.5816}, {4.5826}, 
{4.5836}, {4.5846}, {4.5856}, {4.5866}, {4.5876}, {4.5886}, {4.5896}, 
{4.5906}, {4.5916}, {4.5926}, {4.5936}, {4.5946}, {4.5956}, {4.5966}, 
{4.5976}, {4.5986}, {4.5996}, {4.6006}, {4.6016}, {4.6026}, {4.6036}, 
{4.6046}, {4.6056}, {4.6066}, {4.6076}, {4.6086}, {4.6096}, {4.6106}, 
{4.6116}, {4.6126}, {4.6136}, {4.6146}, {4.6156}, {4.6166}, {4.6176}, 
{4.6186}, {4.6196}, {4.6206}, {4.6216}, {4.6226}, {4.6236}, {4.6246}, 
{4.6256}, {4.6266}, {4.6276}, {4.6286}, {4.6296}, {4.6306}, {4.6316}, 
{4.6326}, {4.6336}, {4.6346}, {4.6356}, {4.6366}, {4.6376}, {4.6386}, 
{4.6396}, {4.6406}, {4.6416}, {4.6426}, {4.6436}, {4.6446}, {4.6456}, 
{4.6466}, {4.6476}, {4.6486}, {4.6496}, {4.6506}, {4.6516}, {4.6526}, 
{4.6536}, {4.6546}, {4.6556}, {4.6566}, {4.6576}, {4.6586}, {4.6596}, 
{4.6606}, {4.6616}, {4.6626}, {4.6636}, {4.6646}, {4.6656}, {4.6666}, 
{4.6676}, {4.6686}, {4.6696}, {4.6706}, {4.6716}, {4.6726}, {4.6736}, 
{4.6746}, {4.6756}, {4.6766}, {4.6776}, {4.6786}, {4.6796}, {4.6806}, 
{4.6816}, {4.6826}, {4.6836}, {4.6846}, {4.6856}, {4.6866}, {4.6876}, 
{4.6886}, {4.6896}, {4.6906}, {4.6916}, {4.6926}, {4.6936}, {4.6946}, 
{4.6956}, {4.6966}, {4.6976}, {4.6986}, {4.6996}, {4.7006}, {4.7016}, 
{4.7026}, {4.7036}, {4.7046}, {4.7056}, {4.7066}, {4.7076}, {4.7086}, 
{4.7096}, {4.7106}, {4.7116}, {4.7126}, {4.7136}, {4.7146}, {4.7156}, 
{4.7166}, {4.7176}, {4.7186}, {4.7196}, {4.7206}, {4.7216}, {4.7226}, 
{4.7236}, {4.7246}, {4.7256}, {4.7266}, {4.7276}, {4.7286}, {4.7296}, 
{4.7306}, {4.7316}, {4.7326}, {4.7336}, {4.7346}, {4.7356}, {4.7366}, 
{4.7376}, {4.7386}, {4.7396}, {4.7406}, {4.7416}, {4.7426}, {4.7436}, 
{4.7446}, {4.7456}, {4.7466}, {4.7476}, {4.7486}, {4.7496}, {4.7506}, 
{4.7516}, {4.7526}, {4.7536}, {4.7546}, {4.7556}, {4.7566}, {4.7576},
{4.7586}, {4.7596}, {4.7606}, {4.7616}, {4.7626}, {4.7636}, {4.7646}, 
{4.7656}, {4.7666}, {4.7676}, {4.7686}, {4.7696}, {4.7706}, {4.7716}, 
{4.7726}, {4.7736}, {4.7746}, {4.7756}, {4.7766}, {4.7776}, {4.7786}, 
{4.7796}, {4.7806}, {4.7816}, {4.7826}, {4.7836}, {4.7846}, {4.7856}, 
{4.7866}, {4.7876}, {4.7886}, {4.7896}, {4.7906}, {4.7916}, {4.7926}, 
{4.7936}, {4.7946}, {4.7956}, {4.7966}, {4.7976}, {4.7986}, {4.7996}, 
{4.8006}, {4.8016}, {4.8026}, {4.8036}, {4.8046}, {4.8056}, {4.8066}, 
{4.8076}, {4.8086}, {4.8096}, {4.8106}, {4.8116}, {4.8126}, {4.8136}, 
{4.8146}, {4.8156}, {4.8166}, {4.8176}, {4.8186}, {4.8196}, {4.8206}, 
{4.8216}, {4.8226}, {4.8236}, {4.8246}, {4.8256}, {4.8266}, {4.8276}, 
{4.8286}, {4.8296}, {4.8306}, {4.8316}, {4.8326}, {4.8336}, {4.8346}, 
{4.8356}, {4.8366}, {4.8376}, {4.8386}, {4.8396}, {4.8406}, {4.8416}, 
{4.8426}, {4.8436}, {4.8446}, {4.8456}, {4.8466}, {4.8476}, {4.8486}, 
{4.8496}, {4.8506}, {4.8516}, {4.8526}, {4.8536}, {4.8546}, {4.8556}, 
{4.8566}, {4.8576}, {4.8586}, {4.8596}, {4.8606}, {4.8616}, {4.8626}, 
{4.8636}, {4.8646}, {4.8656}, {4.8666}, {4.8676}, {4.8686}, {4.8696}, 
{4.8706}, {4.8716}, {4.8726}, {4.8736}, {4.8746}, {4.8756}, {4.8766}, 
{4.8776}, {4.8786}, {4.8796}, {4.8806}, {4.8816}, {4.8826}, {4.8836}, 
{4.8846}, {4.8856}, {4.8866}, {4.8876}, {4.8886}, {4.8896}, {4.8906}, 
{4.8916}, {4.8926}, {4.8936}, {4.8946}, {4.8956}, {4.8966}, {4.8976}, 
{4.8986}, {4.8996}, {4.9006}, {4.9016}, {4.9026}, {4.9036}, {4.9046},
{4.9056}, {4.9066}, {4.9076}, {4.9086}, {4.9096}, {4.9106}, {4.9116}, 
{4.9126}, {4.9136}, {4.9146}, {4.9156}, {4.9166}, {4.9176}, {4.9186}, 
{4.9196}, {4.9206}, {4.9216}, {4.9226}, {4.9236}, {4.9246}, {4.9256}, 
{4.9266}, {4.9276}, {4.9286}, {4.9296}, {4.9306}, {4.9316}, {4.9326}, 
{4.9336}, {4.9346}, {4.9356}, {4.9366}, {4.9376}, {4.9386}, {4.9396}, 
{4.9406}, {4.9416}, {4.9426}, {4.9436}, {4.9446}, {4.9456}, {4.9466}, 
{4.9476}, {4.9486}, {4.9496}, {4.9506}, {4.9516}, {4.9526}, {4.9536}, 
{4.9546}, {4.9556}, {4.9566}, {4.9576}, {4.9586}, {4.9596}, {4.9606},
{4.9616}, {4.9626}, {4.9636}, {4.9646}, {4.9656}, {4.9666}, {4.9676}, 
{4.9686}, {4.9696}, {4.9706}, {4.9716}, {4.9726}, {4.9736}, {4.9746}, 
{4.9756}, {4.9766}, {4.9776}, {4.9786}, {4.9796}, {4.9806}};
```

I can't find the convolution, So, how to do this convolution in Mathematica?
The result is

[image]

Comment: You probably want to `Flatten[]` your data.  Also what is the data for as you don't reference it in the rest of your question?

Comment: Change Voi to this: `Voi[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[gd[s]*gl[t - s], {s, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]` and plot this `Plot[{gd[t], gl[t], Voi[t]}, {t, 4, 5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Green], Directive[Thick, Blue], 
 Directive[Thick, Red]}]` and you'll see the red line though it's very close to the x-axis.

Comment: @flinty thank you for you answer , i found the same results but the goal is to find an average curve of these two functions.

Comment: An average like `(gd[t] + gl[t])/2` ?

Comment: According to Wikipedia a Voigt distribution is a convolution of a Gauss distribution and a Cauchy distribution. Neither of your distributions seems to be a Gauss distribution.
Mathematical issues aside: You have a typo in your definition of `fitplot`, where it should read `Voi[t]`.

Comment: If you just need a Voigt distribution, [there's already one in _Mathematica_](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VoigtDistribution.html). You can do `Plot[PDF[VoigtDistribution[1, 1], x], {x, -4, 4}]`

Comment: Thank you for your help, i will try to use Voigt distrubution.